# Does Wasserstein distance require the source and target distributions to have the same mass?

Tags: density-function, distance, wasserstein

If we minimize the Wasserstein loss,

$$W_1 (P_S, P_T) = \underset{\gamma \in \Pi}{\text{min }} \sum_{x,y} |x-y|\gamma(x,y)$$

which means we are looking for the coupling $\gamma(x,y)$ that minimizes the cost of moving mass from the source distribution $P_S$ to the target distribution $P_T$,

- Do the masses of the source and target distributions have to be identical?
- If so or not, how are the masses of $P_T$ and $P_S$ accounted for mathematically in, or when minimizing, the shown formula, or what might be missing/overlooked by the Wasserstein approach overall due to the mass differences?

Comment: The "mass" is the probability: thus, in thinly disguised terms, you are asking whether the total probability in a distribution always has to be the same.  That's given axiomatically.

Comment: you mean that the sum of probabilities is 1 and therefore the mass of all pdf's is equal to 1?

Comment: The Wasserstein distance is defined between probability distributions, which have mass one by definition (as whuber mentioned). You could also consider the earth mover distance, which is equal to the 1st Wasserstein distance when computed between probability distributions. But, it also allows for distributions of unequal mass (they're no longer probability distributions in this case). See section 2.2 in Levina & Bickel (2001) *The earth mover's distance is the mallows distance: Some insights from statistics.*

Comment: Also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance#Extensions) section on Wikipedia

Comment: If pdfs have unequal mass and are no longer probability distributions then what are they?

Comment: @develarist They're not pdfs or probability distributions in that case. They're functions that assign a non-negative 'amount' to each possible location. The total amounts need not be equal. As an example (where the locations and amounts are both discrete) consider non-normalized histograms that count the number of points in each bin

Comment: Let me add as a general remark, it is |x-y| which is the cost here, not $\gamma(x,y)$.

Comment: thanks for the correction